# cannot load such file -- google/api_client/client_secrets

Tags: google-api-client

For a Rails 3.2.2 project, I got this error:
LoadError (cannot load such file -- google/api_client/client_secrets):
app/controllers/subscriptions_controller.rb:2:in ' lib/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:17:incall'

I am also doing the same configuration on another Rails 4 project, and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you solved this, but I tried a several different things until I went into the actual gem directory `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/google-api-client-0.8.3` in my case and found that the permissions were limited.

After changing the permissions using `chmod` I was able to get it to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. But in my case, gems are not stored in "/Library/..." because I installed rubies with rbenv. I doubt the issue in my case was because problem with class loading differently for gems between rails 4 and rails 3.